# Integer rasters referring to same scale using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, raster-calculator, scale, reclassify

I'm using ArcMap 10. I want to display the area of simulated avalanches. I want this area to be divided in different colors depending on the thickness of the deposit. I managed to do that. But I want all the simulated avalanches to refer to the same scale and same legend of thickness. This means that for every simulation a certain range of values of thickness (e.g. from 2m to 4m) falls within the same color. The problem is I need to transform my raster into polygons (for future calculations of area ratios) and to do this it must be integer. So I guess I have two choices: "raster calculator" or "reclassify".

With "raster calculator" I see I obtain my integer raster with the number of classes of thickness I want but the areas are changed a bit (I don't know why).

With "Reclassify" I obtain an integer raster where my areas are essentially the same as before, but it can have a number of classes not higher than the value of thickness it reaches. In other words using the "reclassify" tool  I would have each simulated avalanche with its own scale of thickness and not a common thickness for all my simulations.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your collection of avalanche simulations,

1. Find the minimum and maximum values. Use the [Cell Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Cell_Statistics/009z0000007q000000/) tool to accomplish this.
2. Build a **Remap table** using the min/max values from step 1. Format it as described in the help section of the [Reclassify by Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Reclass_by_Table/009z000000sq000000/) tool.
3. Use the [Reclassify by Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Reclass_by_Table/009z000000sq000000/) tool to reclassify your simulation results to a common scale(as defined in the remap table). Set the **missing_values** parameter to **NODATA**
4. Convert reclassed [rasters to polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Raster_to_Polygon/001200000008000000/)

Comment: there's a step I can't overcome. How to create a remap table. I created one (with excel) with "from" values, "to" values and "output" values, but when I try the reclass by table tool I can select the "from" and "to" fields but there's no selectable choice for the "output" field although I created it.
What am I doing wrong? I did read that any text file is good to create the remap table, but how would I import it in arcmap? That's why I created the excel table.

Comment: I found an alternative solution, though it might be more time consuming. I will just reclassify my simulation rasters, the raster-to-polygon them and then I would add the missing values as polygons (without drawing them). As I go in properties to classify them to the same number of classes I manage to give them the same scale.